# Simpy - when to use yield and when to call the function

Tags: python, simpy

I am trying to use Simpy to model some behavior of moving cars around a city grid.  However, I am having some trouble wrapping my head conceptually around when to use something like

`yield self.env.timeout(delay)`  or `yield env.process(self.someMethod())` 
versus just calling the method `self.someMethod()`.

On a very theoretical level, I understand `yield` statements and generators as to how they apply to iterables but not quite sure how it relates to `Simpy`.

The `Simpy` tutorials are still quite dense.

For example:

```
class Car(object):
    def __init__(self, env, somestuff):
        self.env = env
        self.somestuff = somestuff

        self.action = env.process(self.startEngine())  # why is this needed?  why not just call startEngine()?

    def startEngine(self):
        #start engine here
        yield self.env.timeout(5) # wait 5 seconds before starting engine
        # why is this needed?  Why not just use sleep? 



env = simpy.Environment()
somestuff = "blah"
car = Car(env, somestuff)
env.run()
```

Comment: Comments in Python start with `#`, not with `//`.

Comment: Oops, thanks for that.  I added that commentary after pasting the code in to SO.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

it looks like you did not completely understand generators / async
functions yet.  I comment your code below and hope that it helps 
you to understand what's happening:

```
import simpy

class Car(object):
    def __init__(self, env, somestuff):
        self.env = env
        self.somestuff = somestuff

        # self.startEngine() would just create a Python generator
        # object that does nothing.  We must call "next(generator)"
        # to run the gen. function's code until the first "yield"
        # statement.
        #
        # If we pass the generator to "env.process()", SimPy will
        # add it to its event queue actually run the generator.
        self.action = env.process(self.startEngine()) 

    def startEngine(self):
        # "env.timeout()" returns a TimeOut event.  If you don't use
        # "yield", "startEngine()" returns directly after creating
        # the event.
        #
        # If you yield the event, "startEngine()" will wait until
        # the event has actually happend after 5 simulation steps.
        # 
        # The difference to time.sleep(5) is, that this function
        # would block until 5 seconds of real time has passed.
        # If you instead "yield event", the yielding process will
        # not block the whole thread but gets suspend by our event
        # loop and resumed once the event has happend.
        yield self.env.timeout(5)


env = simpy.Environment()
somestuff = "blah"
car = Car(env, somestuff)
env.run()
```

Comment: This helps me out.  Thank you!